# Adding A Hard Drive To A Specific Directory

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk

I am currently running a Plex server on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My hardware setup includes a 1TB SATA SSD, which currently houses the operating system and the Plex server. Additionally, I have a separate 1TB HDD that I would like to dedicate solely to the Video directory, as the videos are taking up too much space and my server has other functionalities.

Is it possible to mount the entire partition of the HDD to the Video directory, and what would be the best approach to achieve this?

I have already attempted using the mount command with the Videos directory as the destination, but it appeared to erase the contents of the directory. As a precaution, I used Timeshift to revert the system to its previous state before attempting to mount the HDD.

Comment: You need to move the contents of the existing directory to the new disk before mounting it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two possibilities here. Like Daniel says, it doesn't work the way you tried - mounting a hard drive directly to an existing directory.

If you're using raw partitions for filesystems, you're limited in how you can handle this. To see if you're using raw partitions, look at the output of `df`. If the first column of each line says something like `/dev/sdXY` where X is a letter and Y is a number, you're using raw partitions.

If the first column of the output of `df` looks something like `/dev/mapper/name_here`, you're using LVM, which makes it much easier to get the result you want.

At a high level, if you're using LVM, what you would do is:

1. (Optional) Partition the new hard drive so that the first partition is the entire disk.
2. Make the partition you just created (or the entire disk if you don't want to partition) a PV (physical volume). This would be a command similar to `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`.
3. Add the new PV to the volume group (VG) that contains your video filesystem. The VG name should be evident in the `df` output
4. Expand the logical volume and filesystem for your video data. This would be an appropriately-optioned `lvextend` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Plex and this behavior seems strange to say the least. What I assume what happened is:
The mount succeeded and you got the empty drive as /whatever/video.

You can't just add storage to a directory by mounting another device there. It simply does not work like that. You can make a new directory inside your old video directory and mount your new drive there.

Everything else is going to get a lot more complicated and will require complete reorganization of the existing file structure.

Comment: Ok, I had small suspicion that I couldn't just add an HDD like that. Thank you for the response.